# How do you code covaried errors for an SEM?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am re-analyzing data from a published paper using their correlation matrix and reconstructing their SEM. However, I do not know how to code the errors. Specifically, I attempting to code the errors on the "Empathy" and "Teaching Self-Efficacy" variables in the SEM (pictured). How do you code the errors?

[image]

Below is my code:

```
library(MVN)
library(lavaan)
library(haven)
library(semPlot)
library(lavaanPlot)

Goroshit_Hen_cor_mat <- matrix(c(1, 0.11, -0.12, -0.1, -0.09, 0.03,
                                 0.11, 1, .3, -0.01, -0.05, 0.06,
                                 -0.12, 0.3, 1, 0.21, 0.23, 0.24,
                                 -0.1, -0.01, 0.21, 1, 0.56, 0.53,
                                 -0.09, -0.05, 0.23, 0.56, 1, 0.38,
                                 0.03, 0.06, 0.24, 0.53, 0.38, 1),
                               nrow = 6, ncol = 6)
var_names = c("Gender", "Degree", "Years_Teaching", "Emotional_SE", "Empathy", "Teaching_SE")

Goroshit_Hen_cor_mat

var_sds <- c(0.47, 0.42, 10.19, 0.48, 0.43, 0.55)
  
Goroshit_Hen_cov <- cor2cov(Goroshit_Hen_cor_mat, var_sds, names = var_names) 
 
Goroshit_Hen_cov 

Goroshit_Hen_SEM <-"Empathy ~ Emotional_SE
                    Empathy ~ Gender
                    Empathy ~ Degree
                    Empathy ~ Years_Teaching
                    Teaching_SE ~ Emotional_SE
                    Teaching_SE ~ Gender
                    Teaching_SE ~ Degree
                    Teaching_SE ~ Years_Teaching
                    Emotional_SE ~~ Gender
                    Emotional_SE ~~ Degree
                    Emotional_SE ~~ Years_Teaching
                    Gender ~~ Degree
                    Gender ~~ Years_Teaching
                    Degree ~~ Years_Teaching
                    Empathy ~~ Teaching_SE
                    Empathy ~~ Empathy
                    Teaching_SE ~~ Teaching_SE
                    "

Goroshit_Hen_SEM_fit <- sem(Goroshit_Hen_SEM, sample.cov = Goroshit_Hen_cov, sample.nobs = 273)


semPaths(Goroshit_Hen_SEM_fit, "path", whatLabels = "est", edge.label.cex = 1, intercepts = FALSE, residuals = TRUE, curve = 1, curvature = 2, nCharNodes = 8, sizeMan = 6, sizeMan2 = 3, optimizeLatRes = T, rotation = 3, edge.color = "#000000")

summary(Goroshit_Hen_SEM_fit)
```

Answer (score 0):

All double-headed arrows are specified with the `~~` operator, as explained in the `?model.syntax` help page and the [lavaan tutorial](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax1.html).  So you can add this line to your existing syntax

```
Empathy ~~ Teaching_SE
```

But if you merely want to free that parameter, it is not necessary when using the `sem()` or `cfa()` wrappers, which call `lavaan()` with the setting `auto.cov.y=TRUE` (see the `?lavOptions` for a description).  You should see the parameter estimate in your `summary()` output.